# xcode import corresponding files

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I get an error when I try and import corresponding files.

i.e.

UIViewController "VC.h" Imports "CustomObject.h"

CustomObject Imports "VC.h"

Starts giving error expected specifier qualifier list before

Any ideas? I want both objects to be able to call each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.  You need to break the circular dependency by using a *forward declaration*.  A forward declaration says "this is the name of something, but I don't know the full definition of it".

For example:

```
// In VC.h

// Forward declaration of an Objective-C class.  After this, you can now use
// pointers to CustomObject, but you can't cell methods or access properties
// of those objects
@class CustomObject;

@interface MyViewController
{
    CustomObject *obj;
}
@end
```

Then, in the implementation files, you can include both header files with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed response.

This was the solution, I just did not understand fully the first time I read it.

```
//VC.h     calls cannot be made to CustomObject here, however there is not really any need to
@class CustomObject;
@interface VC : ViewController {
  CustomObject* gameController;
// ...

//VC.m     calls made in .m only.
#import "CustomObject.h"
gameController = [CustomObject init];
```

and vice versa in CustomObject

Sorry I didn't post this as a reply to your answer, new here :S